# Scan computer system file using class definition

Tags: python, class, hash, md5

I am new to python and rarely use class definition, I try to run my program but had error occur... Anyone know what happen? Or I had code something wrong? I had been trying for 2days...
This is coding below:

```
import hashlib
import os.path
import os

class QuickScan:
    def md5(self,fname):
        hash_md5 = hashlib.md5()
        try:
            with open(fname, "rb") as f:
                for chunk in iter(lambda: f.read(2 ** 20), b""):
                    hash_md5.update(chunk)
        except Exception:
            pass
        return hash_md5.hexdigest()

    def get_all_abs_paths(self,rootdir):
        viruslist = open('C:/FYP/SecuCOM2022/virusshare.md5.txt','rt')
        virusinside = [l.rstrip() for l in viruslist]
        paths = list()
        virus="detected"
        novirus="clear"
    
        for dirpath,_,filenames in os.walk(rootdir):
            for f in filenames:
              
             paths.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(dirpath, f)))

        for filename in paths:
            print(filename, self.md5(filename))
            if self.md5(filename) in virusinside:
                print(virus)
                os.remove(filename)
            else:
                print(novirus)
        

    filenames=get_all_abs_paths('C:/Users/User/Desktop/irustesting')
```

Below is the error occur:-

```
class QuickScan:
  File "c:\FYP\SecuCOM2022\QuickScanTab.py", line 71, in QuickScan

filenames=get_all_abs_paths('C:/Users/User/Desktop/irustesting')
TypeError: get_all_abs_paths() missing 1 required positional argument: 'rootdir'
```

Comment: You are not instantiating `QuickScan`. Also the line `filenames=get_all_abs_paths(...)` is indented, which means it's within the definition of the class `QuickScan`. You have to call the function on an instance of that class, and do that outside of the class definition.

Comment: Don't feel like you have to use a class just for the sake of using one.

Comment: I was trying calling this function in another python file so I guess I had to make this class

Comment: There is no need for class if that is the only reason. Regular function (vs. class/method) will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`get_all_abs_paths()` is instance ttribute (method) of class `QuickScan`. You need to instantiate object of class `QuickScan` and call its `get_all_abs_paths()`

```
scan = QuickScan()
scan.get_all_abs_paths('C:/Users/User/Desktop/irustesting')
```

Also, note that this method does not have explicit return, so it does return `None` and your code where you bind the return value to name `filenames` does not make much sense.

Also, you need to unindent it one level, at the moment `filenames=get_all_abs_paths('C:/Users/User/Desktop/irustesting')` is inside the class.

Comment: Omg thanks for that! It makes me feel so dumb asking the stupid question... Thanks so much and thanks for the explanation!